# A proposal to have a score for a comment

Tags: discussion, reputation

I would propose a `+1` point for the important comments that are voted by the users. Is it possible to do something?

See the figure below:

[image]

Comment: note that such things are part of the mechanics of the whole network and can not be changed just for tex.sx, so the proposal would have to be raised network wide at meta.stackexchange not here. However I would guess they would close this in the basis that comments are downplayed by design.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82685

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you so much for your availability and response. Thanks again.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Ok! Thank you so much for the link.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the reputation system is not unique to tex.se, thus this should be asked on meta.se and not here

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, otherwise, you'll get reputation points for a standard comment like this:

[image]

Or funny comments like these:

[image]

However, you can earn some badges for comments:

[image]

Please remember that we are here to help the other users, not to compete for reputation (egreg and David excluded).

Comment: Overall I agree with you but in support of @Sebastiano I'd like to mention that also for questions and answers parts of the upvotes happen because others find the answer sort of cool. Consider for instance a nice looking Ti*k*Z picture, which may not really be considered a true progress in LaTeX coding, but just look appealing. Similarly, some comments can be really help people understanding things better, and others of course get upvoted because they are cool. But overall I agree with you, and also think it would not be worth the effort.

Comment: @marmot Unfortunately, you're right about the voting behavior of TEX.SE users. Often they upvote trivial answers only because they are beautiful or funny, whereas TeXnically complex ones go (almost) unnoticed. There are also people who upvote _just-do-it-for-me_ questions! I think prof. van Duck will address this topic in one of the next issues. However, comments are thought to be only of auxiliary help, see: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/why-do-people-answer-in-comments

Comment: There are occasions where the first comment hits the nail on the head regarding the possible solution, a similar comment is posted by someone else, getting comment votes beyond any limit and the first one is disregarded.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You're right, there are inexplicable behaviors!

Comment: @CarLaTeX: No, it's the fact that some users get votes just because they are X or Y...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  Yes, that's one of the reasons!

Comment: I should flag this answer

Comment: @CarLaTeX What competition? Do you see any chance for one? `;-)`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle :P

Comment: @egreg Actually... the comeback is very difficult!

Comment: I have the [highest voted comment here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7556/a-proposal-to-have-a-score-for-a-comment/7557?noredirect=1#comment22572_7557), if only those votes counted!

Comment: I hope no one got angry. I do not like quarrels. I wish you all the best for everyone and thanks for everything.

Comment: @Sebastiano Of course no! We are only joking! Don't worry, your question is a valid one!

Comment: @CarLaTeX I'm happy. But I'm a commentator? :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano Of course you are, on the main site.

Comment: @CarLaTeX But nobody votes my question? :)

Comment: @Sebastiano You have two upvotes and two downvotes, that's why you see 0 scores. If you click on the number 0 you should see them. But the upvotes in Meta questions give no reputation points.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I saw it now. Sorry very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano Don't worry, your question is appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

Comments have always been considered lower-class citizens across the entire network. They're meant to request clarification, but otherwise clutter the main aim of the site. What is this aim? ...to pair up good *questions* with solid *answers*.

Attempting to make comments just like posts have been proposed:

- [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/168244)
  This is an [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) that questions why you can post content (questions and/or answers) with only 1 reputation point.
- [Cancelling upvote on comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1170/168244) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Yet they remain small potatoes:

- [Allow downvoting comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3615/168244) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
- [Allow more than one @name notification per comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45273/168244) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
- [Reputation for comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296/168244) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

In fact, there are actually [Winterbash hats](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/) dedicated to clearing up comments:

[image]

[image]

Reputation gained from comments may not give a true reflection of reputation.

Related:

- [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/168244)

Comment: Very nice :-). In fact I have voted +1 you and @CarLaTeX.